# Run Razor Pages Web App on Mac OS with Entity Framework and MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, razor-pages, visual-studio-mac

I have a Razor Pages web app that was created in Visual Studio on Window 10. The app all works fine as intended.

I am now wanting to run this on a Mac as I no longer have access to a Windows machine. I have setup the connection to the MySql database and the connection seems to be there.

However I am getting the following error message

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
MySqlException: Unknown column 'u.AccessFailedCount' in 'field list'
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
```

I think it could be due to the tables etc missing however I'm unsure on how to generate/build the tables on a Mac, as normally Entity Framework would handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may (I think) have solved the issue I am facing however I'm not sure if it is the best solution. I have the below class for the ApplicationDbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        this.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Adding the 2 lines below

```
this.Database.EnsureDeleted();
this.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

and running the code then removing them afterwards seemed to solve the issue.